# Retrieve full user profile using facebook oauth token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am building an android app with facebook SDK for oauth. I have an access token and userid.

When I make an http request using that token and userid, I get this json:

```
{
  "name": "Robel Alemu",
  "id": "994449194002838"
}
```

but since that token has permissions for both `public_profile` and `user_friends`, why am I getting only name and id?

This is my code:

```
new GraphRequest(
  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),
        null,
        httpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /* handle the result */
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

Here is a picture of the token which I got from debugging

[image]

Comment: You need to specify the fields you want in the request

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fields param e.g.

```
$ fbapi '/v2.6/me?fields=first_name,relationship_status,gender,locale'
{
  "first_name": "Yuri",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "id": "999999999999"
}
```